# Magento 2 PWA Studio: Issue with SSL certificate

Tags: magento2, ssl, pwa

I'm using Adobe Commerce 2.4.4 with PWA Studio and I don't have a valid SSL validation in my browser during the local development.

[image: Magento 2 PWA local SSL]

For the documentation, it should be working fine.

How could I debug and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To work with a custom hostname and SSL certificate in your local environment you need to run this command below first.

```
yarn buildpack create-custom-origin ./
```

#### Linux

On Linux, make sure you have the package `libnss3-tools` installed.